# Tensorflow Deep neural network code implementation

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I recently tried on building a deep NN for identifying image between 1 and 0 from scratch. My codes seems to be having a very low accuracy and I am wondering why. Since I am still a beginner, I do not know how to check and also to evaluate my model. Is there a way to improve while at the same time check each dataset to print and see whether the model predicted correctly?

My dataset is from here: https://www.kaggle.com/kanncaa1/deep-learning-tutorial-for-beginners

My codes:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
# from builtins import FileExistsError
from subprocess import check_output
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import os
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use("Agg")
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

dirName = "input_file"

try:
    # Create a directory
    os.mkdir(dirName)
    print("directory " + dirName + " created")
except:
    # If directory exists
    print("directory " + dirName + " exists \n")

# Extract the zipfile to the directory
with ZipFile("sign-language-digits-dataset.zip", "r") as zip_data:
    zip_data.extractall("input_file")

# Print the files
print("List of files:")
print(check_output(["ls","input_file"]))

# Load data
x_data = np.load("input_file/X.npy")
y_data = np.load("input_file/Y.npy")

X = np.concatenate((x_data[204:409], x_data[822:1027] ), axis=0)
# Is there a way to improve this part? from here
first_zeros = np.zeros(205)
first_ones = np.ones(205)
zeros = list(zip(first_zeros, first_ones))
second_zeros = np.zeros(205)
second_ones = np.ones(205)
ones = list(zip(second_ones, second_zeros))
ones = np.asarray(ones)
zeros = np.asarray(zeros)
# to here???
Y = np.concatenate((zeros, ones), axis=0).reshape(X.shape[0],2)
# Create 25% for test data and random state is the seed with randomly picked
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25,
                                                    random_state=42)
try:
    if len(X_train) == len(Y_train):
        print("Both have {} lengths".format(len(X_train)))
except:
    print("Different length")

X_train_flatten = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],
                                  X_train.shape[1]*X_train.shape[2])
X_test_flatten = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0],
                                X_test.shape[1]*X_test.shape[2])

# Network parameters
h_layer = 255
h_layer2 = 255
num_input = X_train_flatten.shape[1] # .shape is used for getting the shape
num_classes = Y_train.shape[1] # .shape is used for getting the shape

# parameters
learning_rate = 0.1
num_steps = 500
batch_size = 128
display_step = 100

# tf graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_input]) #4096 because these are the
#image size which required to be trained
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes]) #1 because these are the
# output values that are either 0 or 1 in 2D but only 1 column

# Weight and bias

weights = {
        "h1":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input, h_layer])),
        "h2":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layer, h_layer2])),
        "output":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layer2, num_classes]))
        }

biases = {
        "h1":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layer])),
        "h2":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([h_layer2])),
        "output":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))
        }

# Create model
def neural_network(x):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights["h1"]), biases["h1"])
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights["h2"]), biases["h2"])
    output = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights["output"]), biases["output"])
    return output

# Construct model
logits = neural_network(x)

# Define loss and optimizer

loss =  tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for step in range(1, num_steps+1):
        if step % display_step == 0 or step == 1:
            # feed_dict takes values from the placeholder which is the tf
            # graph input in the form of 2D - (410, 4096) shape
            loss_val, accuracy_val = sess.run([loss, accuracy],
                                              feed_dict={x:X_train_flatten,
                                                         y:Y_train})
            print("Step " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                      "{:.4f}".format(loss_val) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                      "{:.3f}".format(accuracy_val))

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Calculate accuracy for MNIST test images
    print("Testing Accuracy:", \
        sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: X_test_flatten,
                                      y: Y_test}))
```

My side question:

1) My class should be [zero, one] so that means I have 2 classes. The output should be identifying the image input which is in pixels 4096 and output either 0 and 1. For example, if "0" then it will output [1,0] and for "1" it will output [0,1].

2) Is my code even considered as DNN or just a simple NN? If it is not DNN then how should I change it so that it could become DNN?

3) From my understanding, DNN do not require manual feature extraction because it learns from the training data and then perform classification. Unlike machine learning. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: I think it's considered as deep learning NN because this code having 2 hidden layers. To improve the accuracy you can try to find the optimal number of hidden layers, hidden nodes or other parameters that will affect your result by taking experiment. There are many research paper related to NN you can get on the Internet. I think they are quite helpful on finding the optimal setting of the parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response. From my understanding, as long as we have multiple or many layers, it is considered to be deep learning, am I right? In your opinion, is there anything wrong with my understanding based on my questions? If possible, do you have any idea how can I shorted and improve from line 44 to 52? Thank you again sir

Comment: Yes, you are right. If the ANN having multiple hidden layers, it can be considered to be deep learning. BTW, this is only one of the deep learning NN types. To get more understanding on Deep learning NN, you can surf on this website: (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/deep-learning/9781491924570/ch04.html). To select the suitable type of DLNN, it's depending on the nature of your problem.

Comment: One more thing you can do to improve your accuracy is to find the optimal ratio of your data set. From your code, I can see that you are dividing the data set to 75:25 for training and testing data set respectively. Maybe you can try on 80:20 or 70:30 and find the optimal one which get the best result.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the sharing. I will look into the link you have shared to me. I will also try to make some changes to my parameters. Thank you